# how to implement customized hyphenation patterns

Tags: texlive, hyphenation, linux

I created a file with nonstandard hyphenation patterns of my own, but I do not know how to force LaTeX into using my patterns instead of the default ones.

I am using Linux Mint, with pdflatex to compile my '.tex' files. I discovered a `dumylang` option and a `dumyhyph.tex` file, meant for "testing new hyphenation patterns", which is exactly what I wish to do. So far, however, I have not been able to activate them.

My file of patterns has the following content:

```
\patterns{ 
 1p 1t 1c 1k 1j 1w t2r 
 1fe 1fa 1fo 1fi 1fy 1fu 
 1re 1ra 1ro 1ri 1ry 1ru  
 1se 1sa 1so 1si 1sy 1su 
%
%...deleted lines...
%
 kyle me2ke ky2nu ni2e fa2l r2ke 
 u2je u2ma i2jau ru2me 
 e2m a2m o2m i2m y2m u2m nh2ma nh2mu 
 3e2le 3e2la 3e2lo 3e2li 3e2ly 3e2lu 
 }
%\dump
```

How should I proceed? (Please be detailed, since my experience with TeX and Linux is very limited)

Comment: you need to remake the format (or use luatex) in classic tex pdftex and xetex  patterns can only be loaded at format making time, not in a normal typesetting run

Comment: Not writing an answer because I’ve never tried this myself, but, as far as I know, it should suffice to save your hyphenation pattern file into `$TEXMFHOME/tex/generic/hyphen/dumyhyph.tex` (say) and rebuild the format.

Comment: … assuming that you have got TeX Live! (:-)

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: I do not have a folder "$TEXMFHOME/tex/generic/hyphen", but I do have a folder "/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/hyphen", where I placed my hyphenation patterns. When I try to run "update-language-dat" from a terminal it asks for "the configuration directory", but I do not have an idea where such a directory might be, whether I should create it, or what its use is.

Comment: @Goswin: 1) Type `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` to learn what `$TEXFHOME` should expand to on your system.  2) Let’s say the answer is `/home/mickeymo/texmf`; then you should create any directory in the path `/home/mickeymo/texmf/tex/generic/hyphen/` that doesn’t exist yet; after this, try proceeding as I’ve indicated in my previous comment.  There shouldn’t be any need to rebuild the `language.dat` file, only the TeX format(s) need to be rebuilt (but remember, I’ve never actually tried this out! :-) .

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: Ok, now I created the path /home/goswin/texmf/tex/generic/hyp‌​‌​hen/, but how do I (as you tell me) "rebuild the format"? Obviously not by running `update-language-dat --conf-dir /home/goswin/texmf/tex/generic/hyphe‌​n/`, since I already tried that one: I get the error message`Language definition file dumylang.ldf not found`

Comment: @Goswin: (always without any warranty, either express or implied…! :-) in a directory of your choice, type the following at the shell prompt: `pdftex -ini -jobname latex -output-format pdf -etex pdflatex.ini`; after a short (?) while, you’ll get the prompt again, and you should find that a file `latex.fmt` has been created in the current directory; move that file into `/home/goswin/texmf/web2c/`.  I guess you’ll have to create the `web2c` directory inside `/home/goswin/texmf/`.

Comment: @Goswin: No, you should **not** uncomment the line of your hyphenation pattern file that says `%\dump`.

Comment: @Goswin: I forgot to add, after moving `latex.fmt` to `$TEXMFHOME/web2c/`, run `mktexlsr`.  After that, the format file `latex.fmt` that you have just made (which contains a customized LaTeX format that should include your new hyphenation patterns for the language `dumylang`) should take precedence over the system one.  When you want to disable it and return to the original, simply rename it to `latex.fmt.disabled` (say) and run `mktexlsr` again.  All this, always assuming a TeX Live distribution.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: The run failed with several error messages:  `Illegal parameter number in definition of \bbl@line`,  `Illegal parameter number in definition of \bbl@tempa`,  `I can't find file '/etc/texmf/hyphen.d/'`, and  `Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`.  This last one worries me most: after all, you did not expect to obtain a PDF file, but rather a `latex.fmt` file.  (I believe that I have a TeX Live distribution because of the existence of that `/usr/share/texmf-texlive` directory, which I did not create myself)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44253/discussion-between-gustavo-mezzetti-and-goswin).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti It is NOT necessary to run `mktexlsr` if files are installed in TEXMFHOME. @ OP You should NEVER install files manually into the distribution TEXMF tree or into directories managed by your Linux distro's package manager. You should (carefully!) undo the changes you made there. In addition, if you erroneously followed the advice to run `mktexlsr`, you may need to do this again after undoing your changes.

Comment: @cfr: Thank you for your clarification about `mktexlsr`.  I don’t think that the user succeded in modifying the texmf tree of her/his distribution.

Comment: @cfr: I manually modified the protected `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/` tree and the protected `/etc/texmf/` tree with the help of sudo. However, I only added files and did not modify existing ones, except of course `dumyhyph.tex`, of which I have a backup. I ran that useless `update-language-dat` several times and do not know whether it messed something up.

Comment: As I say, you should undo the changes you made. You can always run `update-language-dat` or whatever again if it might have messed something up. (I have no idea.) Just do it after undoing your changes.

Comment: @cfr: ok, and what next?

Comment: That's it for undoing. For doing, follow @GustavoMezzetti 's advice. Or use `fmtutil`, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partial answer I tried to give in my comments to the question couldn’t work, for at least two reasons:

- a format file in the personal texmf tree (`$TEMFHOME`) is *not*
  permitted to override a system format file by the same name
  (quite wisely);
- in any case, the name of the format for the pdfTeX engine should be
  `pdflatex.fmt`, not `latex.fmt`.

So, the best thing is to give the custom format a custom name (seems wise too).  I’ll explain step by step a possible way to proceed, that, this time, I tested myself.  **Please note that the following instructions assume a TeX Live distribution!**

First of all, create a temporary directory in any location of your file system; henceforth, this directory will be referred to as `FOO/`.  Next, let’s say that your custom hyphenation file looks like this:

```
% It's a dummy file dumyhyph.tex created for testing purposes.
% This file is normally defined in language.dat et may be used by language
% styles such as french.sty to define a temporary language. B. Gaulle 23/10/91

\begingroup
\patterns{ % dummy patterns
.ach4
z4zy
% I add a pattern that does permit hyphenation:
aa5a
% (hyphenation will be possible only at places where at least three consecutive 
% "a" characters occur).
}
\endgroup
```

This is only an example, of course, but it is the example I shall use below.  Note that it defines only *one* permissible hyphenation, namely `aa-a`.

We’ll add at the end of this file the following line

```
\gdef\ParapaPonziPonziPo{*** This is my home-made LaTeX format! ***}
```

We do so just to have a means to check with greater ease that our custom format, and not the system one, is being loaded during a TeX run.  So, our file now looks like this:

```
% It's a dummy file dumyhyph.tex created for testing purposes.
% This file is normally defined in language.dat et may be used by language
% styles such as french.sty to define a temporary language. B. Gaulle 23/10/91

\begingroup
\patterns{ % dummy patterns
.ach4
z4zy
% I add a pattern that does permit hyphenation:
aa5a
% (hyphenation will be possible only at places where at least three consecutive 
% "a" characters occur).
}
\endgroup
\gdef\ParapaPonziPonziPo{*** This is my home-made LaTeX format! ***}
```

Save it in `FOO/dumyhyph.tex`; note that the basename `dumyhyph.tex` *must* be used.  After this, make `FOO` your current directory.

We’ll call our custom format `pdflatexmyhyphen`; so, from within the `FOO` directory, issue the following command at the shell prompt:

```
pdflatex -ini -etex -jobname pdflatexmyhyphen pdflatex.ini
```

After a short while, you’ll get the shell prompt again; you should now find that `FOO` contains the following files:

```
dumyhyph.tex
pdflatexmyhyphen.fmt
pdflatexmyhyphen.log
texsys.aux
```

Spend a minute to take a look at the transcript file `pdflatexmyhyphen.log`; scroll down until you find where it says

```
===========================================
Local configuration file hyphen.cfg used
===========================================
```

…some lines omitted…

```
\l@usenglish=\language0
\l@USenglish=\language0
\l@american=\language0
\l@dumylang=\language1

(./dumyhyph.tex)
```

The lines that says `(./dumyhyph.tex)` proves that the file `dumyhyph.tex` was input from the current directory, contrary to the other hyphenation pattern files.

OK, now run the command

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
```

to learn where your system assumes your personal texmf tree is located; let’s say that the answer is

```
/home/donalddu/texmf
```

Then, create any missing directory in the path

```
/home/donalddu/texmf/web2c/
```

(note that `/home/donalddu/` is supposed to be your home directory, so you can do so *without* any need for super-user privileges); finally, move—or copy—the file `pdflatexmyhyphen.fmt` from `FOO/` to `/home/donalddu/texmf/web2c/`.

That’s all; as @cfr remarked, there’s no need to run `mktexlsr`: your custom format, containing your custom hyphenation patterns, is ready for use.

So, let’s try it out, by compiling the following file—let us call it `TryMyHyphenation.tex`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\ifdefined\ParapaPonziPonziPo
    \typeout{\ParapaPonziPonziPo}
\fi

\usepackage[english]{babel}



\begin{document}

This is a paragraph written in English, to which English hyphenation rules 
apply.  It is followed by some other paragraphs written in our ``dummy 
language''; in order to make our custom hyphenation rules apply to them, we 
enclose them within a \texttt{hyphenrules} environment.

\begin{hyphenrules}{dumylang}

The ``dummy language'' is curiously similar to English, except that it doesn't
permit words to be hyphenated at all---or almost so.  Indeed, a peculiarity of
this language is that it includes non-English words like
``mumbawohckijutresxxiukklanghornitudinal'' and ``axaxaxaaaxaxaxa'', and
that---aha!---hyphenation is permitted when three~``a'' occur in a row.  So,
while, for example, ``mumbawohckijutresxxiukklanghornitudinal'' cannot be
broken, and hence produces ``overfull \verb|\hbox|es'', the word
``axaxaxaaaxaxaxa'' \emph{can} be hyphenated, provided, of course, that you are
using a \LaTeX\ format that incorporates our custom hyphenation patterns.

Another paragraph that again demonstrate this: pneumococcus, axaxaxaaaxaxaxa,
hyperbola, neutrino.

\end{hyphenrules}

\end{document}
```

First, try compiling it with the normal LaTeX format, with the usual command

```
pdflatex TryMyHyphenation
```

and look at the result: you’ll find that the word “axaxaxaaaxaxaxa” is *not* hyphenated.

Next, try compiling it with your new custom format: this can be done by means of the `-fmt` command-line option.  That is, type

```
pdflatex -fmt pdflatexmyhyphen TryMyHyphenation
```

Two thing should now happen:

1. during the compilation, you should see the message

   ```
   *** This is my home-made LaTeX format! ***
   ```

   and also find it in the transcript file;
2. TeX should now be able to hyphenate the word “axaxaxaaaxaxaxa”.

Here is the output I get in the second run:

[image: Output obtained with the custom format]

---

## Alternative method: Using `fmtutil` to replace the original format

Yesterday I hadn’t tested this method yet, so I didn’t dare recommend it.  Contrary to the previous answer, this time we will not make a custom format by a different name, but we’ll override the `pdflatex.fmt` file itself with our custom version.  Although it is not possible to do this from within the personal texmf tree, it can be done, under TeX Live’s supervision, from a different point of your home directory.  It turns out that this solution is actually easier to carry out than the previous one; but replacing the (pdf)LaTeX format itself is something that not all users might feel comfortable with… `(:-)` (Of course, there are also a lot of good reasons for which even knowledgeable users might simply prefer to avoid doing so.)

So, let’s start again from our custom `dumyhyph.tex` file saved in a directory `FOO/` of our choice (remember that, although the name and the location of the directory are arbitrary, the basename `dumyhyph.tex` *must* be used):

```
% It's a dummy file dumyhyph.tex created for testing purposes.
% This file is normally defined in language.dat et may be used by language
% styles such as french.sty to define a temporary language. B. Gaulle 23/10/91

\begingroup
\patterns{ % dummy patterns
.ach4
z4zy
% I add a pattern that does permit hyphenation:
aa5a
% (hyphenation will be possible only at places where at least three consecutive 
% "a" characters occur).
}
\gdef\ParapaPonziPonziPo{*** This is a home-made TeX format! ***}
\def\typeout{\immediate\write17}
\obeyspaces
\typeout{****************************************************************}
\typeout{*   Custom hyphenation pattern file `dumyhyph.tex' has been    *}
\typeout{*        loaded instead of the original `dumyhyph.tex'!        *}
\typeout{****************************************************************}
\endgroup
```

As you can see, I’ve added a few banner lines, that will be displayed during the format-making process.  Make `FOO/` your current directory and issue one of the following commands:

- if you want to rebuild only the `pdflatex.fmt` format file, issue

  ```
  mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
  ```

  (this is what I recommend, at least for testing purposes);
- if you want to rebuild *all* formats for the pdfTeX engine, issue

  ```
  fmtutil --byengine pdftex
  ```

  (are you sure that this is what you want?).

A lot of messages will flash on the terminal: one of them, displayed shortly before you get the shell prompt again, is important.  It tells you where your custom format(s) has/have been installed, and it looks like this:

```
fmtutil: /home/mezzetti/.texmf-var/web2c/pdflatex.fmt installed.
```

**Take note of this location!**  It’s system-dependent, and you might need it when you want to get rid of the custom format.

Assuming the location indicated above, you should also find a transcript file named

```
/home/mezzetti/.texmf-var/web2c/pdflatex.log
```

Open it: it should contain the following lines, more or less around line 400:

```
===========================================
Local configuration file hyphen.cfg used
===========================================
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/hyphen.cfg
File: hyphen.cfg 2016/02/24 3.9q Babel hyphens

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2016/02/24 3.9q Babel switching mechanism
)
\l@english=\language0

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
\l@usenglish=\language0
\l@USenglish=\language0
\l@american=\language0
\l@dumylang=\language1

(/Users/gustavo/Desktop/FOO/dumyhyph.tex
****************************************************************
*   Custom hyphenation pattern file `dumyhyph.tex' has been    *
*        loaded instead of the original `dumyhyph.tex'!        *
****************************************************************
)
```

This confirms that our custom hyphenation file was used (and, yes, it also shows that the system on which this example was generated is not very up-to-date…)

You are done.  From now on, the format that incorporates your custom patterns will be used instead of the original one: no need to use any `-fmt` option, just compile as usual.

When you want to get rid of the custom format(s), go back to your note and remove anything under `.../web2c/`, including the directory `.../web2c` itself.  For example, assuming the location shown above, you’d go

```
rm -rf /home/mezzetti/.texmf-var/web2c/
```

To show another example, if the message you got after running `mktexfmt` had been

```
mktexfmt [INFO]: /Users/gustavo/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt installed.
```

you would issue the following command

```
rm -rf /Users/gustavo/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/web2c/
```

to restore the distribution formats.

Comment: I tried your first method. The command `pdflatex -ini -etex -jobname pdflatexmyhyphen pdflatex.ini` failed to produce a `pdflatexmyhyphen.fmt` file; it reports problems with file `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/hyphen.cfg` (unmodified since 2008), it also could not find file `/etc/texmf/hyphen.d/`, but that hyphen.d is a directory, not a file. Is there a way of sending you the pdflatexmyhyphen.log file it produced?

Comment: I might have messed up things by formerly running `update-language-dat --conf-dir ~/texmf/tex/generic/hyphen/` or `update-language-dat --conf-dir /home/goswin/texmf/tex/generic/hyphen/`, which I did not know how to undo.

Comment: @Goswin: Why the semicolon in /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/‌​;babel/hyphen.cf‌​g?

Comment: @ Gustavo Mezzetti: I do not know; there is no semicolon in the file `pdflatexmyhyphen.log`. It was introduced by the stackexchange-software when I saved the comment; maybe an invisible character that became visible, it disappeared when I typed in the path by hand.

Comment: This looks great! And thanks for the clarification in chat - it is good to know I'm not *quite* as confused as I thought ;).

Comment: @Goswin Do you have a directory `.texliveYYYY` where `YYYY` is the edition of TeX Live you are using? If so, try removing it. Unless you used root privileges to modify stuff, any changes you made should be there (other than stuff you actually added into your personal TEXMF tree). Removing it can't do any harm - anything you need should be automatically regenerated. But you can move rather than deleting it to be on the safe side, just by renaming it.

Comment: @cfr: I did not find any such directory ('texlive'+exactly_4_characters), which path is that supposed to be in? By now, I succeeded in completely removing tex-common and texlive and in reinstalling them. That worked flawlessly (it did not before), but Mezzettis command `pdflatex -ini -etex -jobname pdflatexmyhyphen pdflatex.ini` still gave the error messages: `(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/hyphen.cfg`, 
`! Illegal parameter number in definition of \bbl@line.`, `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \languagename.`, ..., `! I can't find file `/etc/texmf/hyphen.d/`

Comment: I'd expect `~/.texliveYYYY` but the packagers for your distro might have changed it. That's the default.

Comment: **Success!**  In my home directory there still was an old hidden folder named `.texmf-var`, which apparently caused the pdflatex command to crash. I just removed it and a file `pdflatexmyhyphen.fmt` was generated. The rest I will check later.

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: **Everything worked out fine** as you predicted, the only thing that should be added to the answer is "clean up your home directory from (possibly hidden) old TeX folders like `.texmf-var`". But am I _really_ forced to call my file of hyphenation patterns `dumyhyph.tex` or can I define more than one file with hypenation patterns and switch from one to another in my code?

Comment: @Goswin: The “language” `dumyhyph.tex` is listed in the original `language.dat` file, and that’s why that particular name works “out of the box”.  You may, of course, name your hyphenation file differently, or use several custom hyphenation files, but you need to add them to `language.dat`.  I’ve never modified `language.dat` myself: ***in theory,*** I know how to do this in TeX Live, but maybe you’ve got the Debian version, that possibly uses a different method.